# Windows 10 occupies 80% of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

Recently I've noticed that 80% and more of RAM (my laptop have 8GB RAM) is being occupied on startup, but in the task manager the sum of all processes' memory usage is less than 2GB. Here is the screenshots of the task manager and resource monitor:

[image: taskman_1]

[image: taskman_2]

[image: resmon]

[google chrome tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fODZA.jpg)

Is there a way to solve this issue without reinstalling the OS ?

Comment: Did you check what those 28 Chrome tabs add up to? - click the reveal arrow, they're not included in the top figure. Chrome is a well-known memory hog.

Comment: Start it up, do not load Chrome or any other application. Just let it idle. How much memory is being used?  It should not be more that 4 GB at idle.

Comment: @John Almost 6GB and rising.

Comment: Check for viruses and malware - Full scan with Windows Defender

Comment: Task Manager is useless in a case like this.  Use RAMMap instead

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1220567/40928