# Can you explain the memory usage by the explorer process? What does Commit mean?

Tags: windows-10

[image: mCR3z3A4#ehxXQkz9rSQ]
Why does the explorer.exe process have a 14GB commit? What does this mean? Computer is behaving very slowly, and this is the only culprit I can think of.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1174229/how-does-memory-commit-charge-work-in-windows-10

Comment: 14GB of committed memory is likely to be some kind of memory leak or interaction with another program.