# Windows never using the last 15% (5GB) of RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 32GB of RAM on my Windows 7 x64 system, but it seems every time I get to around the 85% utilization mark everything starts to go haywire. Windows nonstop complains about low memory, Firefox and Chrome tabs or the entire browsers always crash, my Aero theme always reverts to a basic less memory intensive one etc. I can't figure out why.. Task manager still claims I have 15% memory left, which equates to ~5GB, yet it never uses it. I have 70GB of HD space free on an SSD for paging.

I had this problem when I had 16GB of memory so I doubled it up, but now every application just uses twice as much memory as before and it really didn't solve any problems.

I have tested the memory and there are no errors identified.

What can I do so it uses my entire 32GB of memory in an efficient manner?

Comment: Did you check your pagefile settings? Is it disabled or not set to system managed?

Comment: Most likely this is due to nonsensical pagefile settings making you system unable to use its RAM effectively.

Comment: Windows' "low memory" and "out of memory" messages mean you're running out of commit limit, not RAM. You can run out of commit limit even though you have plenty of RAM. To get rid of these you can either increase the commit limit (by adding RAM, or increasing your pagefile size, or both), or you can run less/smaller stuff at one time. You may wish to review these Qs and my As: https://superuser.com/a/943185/348119 ,  https://superuser.com/a/1199599/348119 , https://superuser.com/a/1174279/348119